# Spring - Using property-placeholder to load properties file that is outside the war file or the classpath but is in the filesystem

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, autowired

I have configured the loading of the properties file as shown below (Spring 3.1)

my-spring-xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:///C:/temp/application.properties"/>
```

web.xml

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>       
        /WEB-INF/my-spring-xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

application.properties

```
expirationOffset = 777
```

In my java class i have declared the property as follows:

```
private @Value("${expirationOffset}") String propertyValue;
```

For some reason the value is not being initialised. When i run the following statement:

```
System.out.println("VALUE - " + propertyValue);
```

The output is always

```
16:03:02,355 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) VALUE - ${expirationOffset}
```

I have tried to move the properties file in to the war file to try and access it while it is in the classpath but still the same problem. Here is how i access it from the classpath.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/conf/application.properties"/>
```

Ideally i would like to keep the properties file outside the war file as i would not want to have to rebuild the war file because of a simple property change.

Have i missed something?

### Edit

I removed the msm-spring.xml initialisation paramters from this context:

```
<context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>       
            /WEB-INF/my-spring-xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
```

and moved it to the servlet context as shown below.

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservice</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/my-spring-xml
            </param-value>          
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

The above change seems to have fixed as i am now getting the correct value. I thought the way i had originally was that i had it on the application context meaning that it will be available throughout the application/webapp.

What is the difference in having the msm-spring in the either of 3 i have listed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of speculation based on the information you have provided:

You probably don't have the `<context:property-placeholder..` in your Root Web Application context - the one loaded by ContextLoaderListener, instead you may be having it in the web context(loaded by Dispatcher servlet). Can you please confirm this.

*Update:* Based on the comment, the issue seems to have been that the `<context:propert-placeholder..` was defined in the Root Web application context, but being referred to in a component from Web Context.

The fix is to move the propertyplaceholder to the web context (one defined through MessageDispatcherServlet) in this case.

Comment: I have it the other way round. property-placeholder is defined as a parameter value for <context-param> but not as an <init param> for the org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet servlet.

Comment: I moved it and now can see the values. See the edit in the original post.

Comment: Cool, I have updated my answer based on this information. The reason why this does not work is probably because the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor and resolves the place holder in the context where it is defined - which in this case is the Root Context, and could not do so for the place holders in the Web Context.

Comment: So if I want to load the properties from the Root web application context configuration and have beans in the [Dispatcher]Servlet context be injected with those property values, then there is no way of doing that? Is it recommended that I load property files in the same configuration file that defines/scans beans that use those properties?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :

Did you try using setter method with `#{expirationOffset}`  ??

i.e. :

```
private String propertyValue;
@Value("#{expirationOffset}")
    public void setPropertyValue(String property) {
        propertyValue = property;
    }
```

**Another Option :**

Add Properties bean instead of PropertyPlaceConfigurer like this :

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="file:///C:/temp/application.properties" />
```

OR

```
<util:properties id="myProps" location="classpath:application.properties" />
```

And Replace Setter with a slight modification as

```
private String propertyValue;
@Value("#{myProps.expirationOffset}")
    public void setPropertyValue(String property) {
        propertyValue = property;
    }
```

You'll have to add `xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"` to `xmlns` decalrations and correcsponding `http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd` to `xsi:schemalocation`  in your context configuration xml.

This should definitely work.!

Hope it Helps. :)

Comment: I just tried that and it is printing "VALUE - #@Value${expirationOffset}" as the output. It seems to me that the spEL is not being interpreted.

Comment: My bad, check answer again.. :(
There shouldnt be '@Value' inside '@Value' :(